# Extract data after network call in Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, nsurlsession

This is a question about the [objc.io video about networking](https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E01-networking).

> Note: I have seen similar questions, but none of the suggestions worked
>   for me.

In the sample code, the main call is:

```
Webservice().load(resource: Episode.all) { result in
    print(result!)
}
```

and the `load` function looks like this:

```
func load<A>(resource: Resource<A>, completion: @escaping (A?) -> ()) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: resource.url as URL) { data, _, _ in
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            completion(resource.parse(data as NSData))

        }.resume()
    }
```

For simplicity they just print the `result` (an array of dictionaries), but I don't understand how I can further use it, because it is inside the closure. This way I can eg show the array in a `UITableView` or something like that.

So what I would like to do is something like:

```
var episodes = [Episode]()

Webservice().load(resource: Episode) { result in
    episodes = result!
}

print(episodes)
```

But this results in an empty array being printed.

I also tried using

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    episodes = result!
}
```

But again, nothing is printed.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: The closure that is called with the episodes is called after the `print` method is called (the data is loaded asynchronously on a background thread). I'm not sure where you are calling `Webservice().load` but you need to assign the episodes to an instance variable, or call a method and pass the episodes through to use them. EDIT: I actually answered something very similar to this only the other day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135839/swift-post-request-in-same-thread/40136161?noredirect=1#comment67582949_40136161

Comment: It's a Playground, and `Webservice().load` is the last line. I will have a look at your other answer.

Comment: `episodes` is only updated when the closure runs, so that's the time you need to show the array (assuming that's what you decide to do).  Either the work can be done inside the closure or the closure can send some kind of notification that the result is ready and have a different part of the code listen for that notification.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about notifications, I'll have a go to see if I can get it to work in a PlayGround.